# How to remove lines if they appear more than once in Notepad++? (removing both lines!)

Tags: notepad++, regex, csv, list

Here's how my .csv looks :

```
36;Masashi MOTOYAMA
38;H. SOGAHATA
38;Hitoshi SOGAHATA
47;Masami IHARA
52;S. ONO
52;S. ONO
```

For my project, I need to add one by one every missing id.

I want to keep the ids that appear only once.

But I have in total 60 000 names in my list.

I'd like to delete all the lines with a number that appears more than once removing both lines, not only one.

For example if I had

```
1
2
2
3
```

I'm not looking for "1,2,3", what I want is :

```
1
3
```

Numbers go from "1;" to "1073878823;"

Some names are written in a different way and don't match, only the number matters.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming you file is sorted**, you can do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(\d+).+\R(?:^\1\b.+\R?)+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    (\d+)       # group 1, 1 or more digits
    .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
    \R          # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
    (?:         # non capture group
        ^           # beginning of line
        \1          # backreference to group 1
        \b          # word boundary
        .+          # 1 or more any character but newline
        \R?         # any kind of linebreak, optional
    )+          # end group, must appear 1 or more times
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you very much!